# ESP32 with Li-po PCB review request

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, esp32, usb-c

I'm making a calculator based on the ESP32 and this is my second iteration of the PCB.

It's using a CH340C for USB to serial, and a TP4056, a DS01, and a SDB628 for battery charging/protection/regulator. I'm a noob at electronics, so any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

ESP32:
[image: esp32]

Charging/protection:
[image: charging/protection]

Voltage regulator:
[image: voltage regulator]

Top PCB:
[image: top pcb]

Bottom PCB:
[image: bottom pcb]

Comment: Review requests are not very good questions. Each answer will not be best but will contain only parts of info. Other than "looks it won't work", is there any specific question?

Comment: Some thoughts: maybe its better to start a 4 layer pcb first, put your signals on layer 1 and 4, make 2 & 3 ground. For every signal via you use, put a ground via next to it. But if you want to stick to the 2 layer (more difficult) pit via stitching everywhere to ground. Some pours on the top layer don’t connect to ground or something else. This can cause a lot of problems (emi). And you are to Dutch with your via’s you already used haha. Make power traces 20 mils and signal 6 mils wide to start with. If you disconnect a large ground path like you did twice, make a ground bridge on top.

Comment: For your power: the inductor is very close to other sensitive parts, put a switched power supply at distance. Also use the space you have: the signal traces to the esp are very close together. I would use at leaste twice the trace width as separation.

Comment: Your uart signals travel under the inductor. Also uart is better to use a differential pair line and as short as possible. Consider esd diodes like the srv-05, because of possible esd via the usb cable.

Comment: And last but not least: don’t give up and just learn from your mistakes :)

Comment: Consider where the reference planes are for your traces. For the most part you've got an unbroken ground plane, which is good. But your TX/RX traces break the ground plane and travel right underneath the +3.3V input for the MCU. The return currents for the power delivery path are likely to travel through your TX/RX traces. This is likely to cause signal integrity problems.